# Check Nullpointer of jsonArray length in return statemnt

Tags: android

here is my code:

```
private JSONArray dataArray;

class ....

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataArray.length();
}
```

Now, I want to check, if the array length is null, I tried with a try catch but it didn't worked.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            return dataArray.length();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe){
            Log.e("ARRAY","is null");
        }
    }
```

because the return statement is missing. How can I solve this?

Comment: NPE occurs when a object is null. If dataArray is null you might get NPE.

Comment: The array length cannot be null. It can be zero and you can check it like `if(dataArray.length() == 0)` or of course `if(dataArray.length() > 0)`.

Comment: @RacilHilan i too got confused length() is fine since its a JSONArray

Comment: Do you want to check if the JSONArray is empty or if the dataArray is a NullPointer? Right now you are checking for the latter. And what do you mean with "it didn't work"? Give us an example of how it is supposed to work.

Comment: the method "getCount" needs a return statement. If I put this in a try catch or something else, the return statement is missing, so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but try this to fix the error:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            return dataArray.length();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe){
            Log.e("ARRAY","is null");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

However, it is always better to check for bad conditions rather than use exceptions. Perhaps you may want to consider coding it this way:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        If(dataArray != null) {
            return dataArray.length();
        }
        else {
            Log.e("ARRAY","is null");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is wonderful! I missed the return statement in the catch..
THANKS!

Comment: Yes, but I think it is better to check if the array is null rather than use the exception. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

although this is not the best method, the following code will work

```
public int getCount() {
        try {
             int len = dataArray.length();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe){
            Log.e("ARRAY","is null");
        }
         return len;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
public int getCount() {
               int len=0;
            if(dataArray !=null && dataArray.length()>0)
             {
                  len = dataArray.length();
             }
             else
              {
               Log.e("ARRAY","is null");
              }
         return len;
        }
```